# I don't understand why I am getting this traceback error!!! Very new by the way

Tags: python, syntax-error, traceback

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGZUt.png)

I have reinstalled everything (python, vsc and tried doing the terminal first, and that is all I could do... please help!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Could you [edit] your question to fix this and better explain what your problem is. Saying you did all you could doesn't tell us what you did

Comment: You're not even using macOS, don't tag xcode

Answer (score 1):

You are just calling `python` in your terminal, which starts the [Python REPL](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/repl/). The REPL doesn't know anything about the code in the file you are editing, which is why calling `monday_temperatures.append(8.1)` on the terminal fails. The variable is not defined.

You can try to move `monday_temperatures.append(8.1)` into the file as a second line. Then you can run the program by typing `python basics.py` in your terminal (assuming that basics.py is in your current directly, otherwise you might have to change directories on the terminal).

This will run your Python script but it won't print anything. To print the list, you can add yet another line to your script: `print(monday_temperatures)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the list with :

```
from myfile import myList
```

but i recommend you to make the operations of the list in the same file

Comment: Maybe explain how the OP can make the operations in the same file? A more detailed explanation is more likely to get you upvotes

Comment: How exactly do I do that... sorry just started yesterday :)